# Powering Raspberry Pi and 11 servos on one battery pack

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, servo

I am working on making Sox from Lightyear using a Raspberry Pi as the main board. I have a PCA9685 servo controller that can drive up to 16 servos using I2C.

The issue I am facing is that my [X728 power supply](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X728) in conjunction with the servos results in low voltage warnings on the Pi with only four servos installed.

I am wondering what to do for power, be it an off the shelf component or a print and solder circuit. The X728 is good to 8A, but from what I read about the 9g servos, each can pull up to an ampere and should be separate from the Raspberry Pi power line.

I currently have four 18650 3500mAh batteries each rated at 8 amperes. If possible, I would like to reuse them. but if not that is ok.

Please let me know what would work. I have seen many Raspberry Pi family based robots, but it seems no one (or at least Google) likes to talk about it.

[Link to youtube video I made talking about hardware, which may be of use to someone.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joA-4yKx4sY&list=PLGEbHiCntvcdCNmfxCJYJBd3z-KsEp31s&index=1)